# Parse iframe with blank src using bs4

Tags: python, parsing, iframe, beautifulsoup

Good time of day, SO community. Here's the problem I recently encountered:

I got this HTML source code on main page:

```
  <div id="contents_layout">

  <iframe name="contentsFrame" id="contentsFrameID" src="" 
  width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

  </div>
```

And I've read a lot of materials on parsing the iframe, but all they do is getting the src attribute from iframe and make another request afterwards. I can't do same trick here as the src attribute is blank and web logic lies underneath.

I'm using Python 3.5, bs4  and requests.

Page source code - http://collabedit.com/kqp88
Frame source code - http://collabedit.com/hwuj7

I don't know if it's okay if I share the original webpage...

Comment: What do you want to do once you get the iframe?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I want to parse it's content, of course.

Comment: I cannot see contents_layout or contentsFrameID anywhere in either source

Comment: That's right, me neither. That is the very problem - I just can't distinguish, what is the page link that iframe loads. And when I look at source code - it's all blank and only has variable names in it, like contentFrameID, or contentTextID.

Comment: The iframe in the second link has the id `vis_frame`, is that what you want? Also how does the first link fit into this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Allright, let me share the [link](http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Index?contents_id=E0000089) and try to explain what I want to get. You will see there the frame that contains the information I am to get. The iframe source is viewable from browser, but not visible for bs4. What bs4 sees is only main page source code. And I need html that iframe loads.

Comment: the problem is the content is created with javascript, what exactly do you want from the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

The *iframe* had an id so just use that:

```
h= """<div id="contents_layout">

  <iframe name="contentsFrame" id="contentsFrameID" src=""
  width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

  </div>
"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

iframe = soup.select_one("#contentsFrameID")
```

which would give you:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" id="contentsFrameID" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="contentsFrame" scrolling="no" src="" width="100%"></iframe>
```

You could also use the  empty *src* attribute:

```
ifr = soup.select_one("iframe[src=""]")
```

Use the name:

```
 ifr = soup.select_one("iframe[name=contentsFrame]")
```

In the actual site you are scraping, the content inside `contentsFrameID` is dynamically created so you will need something like [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), an example below getting dynamically created form:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
dr =  webdriver.PhantomJS()

dr.get("http://encykorea.aks.ac.kr/Contents/Index?contents_id=E0000089")

soup = BeautifulSoup(dr.page_source)
print(soup.select_one("#contentFrameForm")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I `print(iframe)`, it would give me the exact `<iframe> ... </iframe>`. I added source code of the page and iframe to the question, would you take a look on those as well? Thank you very much in advance.