# Can't get src from iframe with beautifulSoup python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract video from a web page with BeautifulSoup in python but i got into some problems.

When i go to the web page and inspect to see html elements I see this tag

```
<iframe id="iframe-embed2" src="https://player.voxzer.org/view/1167612b04f6855ecc4bb5e0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and when i copy the src and open it, it shows me the video.

but when I use BeautifulSoup to find the iframe from the web page I got src as empty string.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = requests.get("the url ...")
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all("iframe"))

>>> [<iframe allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="auto" id="iframe-embed2" mozallowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" src="" webkitallowfullscreen="true" width="100%"></iframe>]
```

What is the problem here?

this question doesn't have any working solutions

[Parse iframe with blank src using bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047178/parse-iframe-with-blank-src-using-bs4)

Comment: Can you post the webpage? That makes it easier to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @DSteman ok here is the web page https://123moviesfree.net/season/silicon-valley-season-2-6026/watching.html

Comment: Please check if `src` is set in what you fetch, i.e. do `print('src="https://player.voxzer.org/view/1167612b04f6855ecc4bb5e0"' in site.text)` immediately after `site = requests`... line and write what is output

Comment: @Daweo it returns True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What is the problem here?*

I looked at `site.text` and found `https://player.voxzer.org/view/1167612b04f6855ecc4bb5e0` to be placed in line

```
mainvideos.push('https://player.voxzer.org/view/1167612b04f6855ecc4bb5e0')
```

as `.push` is JavaScript method, apparently `src` of this iframe is set by JavaScript code, so you will need way to execute JavaScript code of site (for example using Selenium).